# SVN to git migration with git svn returns "update-ref -m r40894 refs/remotes/origin/trunk 22c8704953ab8e....: command returned error: 127

Tags: git, gitlab, git-svn

I am doing SVN to git migration using `git svn`.

We do not intend to use svn2git or subgit, this question is about using `git svn`.

We have already migrated number of repositories and did not have issues until this one.

In order to migrate, I issue:

```
git svn clone -r3328:HEAD https://svnserver/OurSystems/lib --no-metadata --no-minimize-url --authors-file=authors-lib.txt --stdlayout lib
```

For some projects, this command completes entirely, for some other projects, it would fail with "connection reset by peer".  This is not an issue for me, I found that all I got to do is to navigate into created root of "**lib**" project and issue below command from a next higher revision:

```
git svn fetch -r 5226:HEAD
```

, it will continue migrating and eventually complete and I will have all repo files migrated.

However, for my **lib** project (C++), I get following error

**update-ref -m r40894 refs/remotes/origin/trunk 22c8704953ab8e4fd22b99fa2ce7f65b49d5427d: command returned error: 127**

After this, reissuing git svn fetch will consistently error with below no matter what revision I pick to start from:

**open: No such file or directory at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 620.**

As I havent encountered this error before, I am not sure how to deal with it.  Googling is not taking me anywhere.